# While loop that ends with a semiconlon

Tags: c, io

I have the code;

```
    while(nread = read(fd,&c,1)==0);
```

Why is this while loop ending with a semicolon? Isn't this line going to to go through the whole fd without doing anything?

Comment: Seeing just this line of code, there's really no way we can know why it's there and what purpose it serves. I suspect, it's just a mistake.

Comment: I am only trying to know about the syntax. If the while loop ends with a semicolon, is it just going to loop without doing anything?

Comment: It will call `read` and update `nread`.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to have a lot of sense. One thing it does *not* do is going through the whole fd though.

Comment: It's also not assigning the return value of `read` to `nread`.  Instead, it's assigning either 1 or 0 to `nread`, depending on whether `read` returns 0 (since `==` binds more tightly than `=`).  And if it does return 0, it will keep trying endlessly to read more, getting 0 each time.  It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Is there a `do { … }` just before the `while`? Is there a line after the `while` that would make sense if the `;` on the `while` were removed because somebody had accidentally typed it? Was the author of this line of code experienced or inexperienced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty statement does nothing, so

```
while(nread = read(fd,&c,1)==0);
```

is equivalent to

```
while(nread = read(fd,&c,1)==0) { }
```

This is what the statement does:

- If `read` returns 1 (because it read one character), the loop will end immediately (after setting `nread` to `0`).
- If `read` returns 0 (because it reached EOF), it will try to read again (which may or may not return returns 0 again).
- If `read` returns -1 (because an error occurred), it will try to read again (which may or may not return -1 again).

Since this can easily degenerate into an infinite loop, this code is surely broken.

Answer (score -1):

well this gonna be jumping inside the loop forever until the condition is dissatisfied 
so basically
here is a example for a "for" loop

```cpp
for(i=0;i<10;i++);
printf("%d",i);
```

this will print 10 directly instead of the whole number series

Comment: How does this answer the question?